# "Empty" or pointless Git commits never visible?

Tags: git

I ran into a situation today and want to make sure I understand what is going on. If I have a branch off of master that I make a small commit to, then I make that same small commit directly to master, what happens if I attempt to merge the branch with master?

Does nothing happen? When I pushed the merge, no commit for it ever showed up in Git. So does Git just ignore merges that contain net zero changes?

EDIT: When I did this, literally nothing showed up in git. I pushed the changes to master, and that merge and push was never mentioned again. Not in gitk --all, not in my SourceTree branch history, not in my BitBucket commit history. It's like it never happened.

Comment: When you merge it will conflict. When you go to resolve those conflicts, Git will do it automatically for you and will create an empty merge commit. By the way - this seems like something that would be very easy to test yourself?

Comment: Git finds the "merge base" and compares the changes from that to each tip.    You can choose which refs to push, recently the default is to push just your current ref if its upstream has the same name.

Comment: What precisely git you type to merge, and what did git show you? Did you get any unexpected messages? Did you see a merge commit on your local system before you pushed?

Comment: Did it fast-forward?

Comment: When I did this, literally nothing showed up in git. I pushed the changes to master, and that merge and push was never mentioned again. Not in gitk --all, not in my SourceTree branch history, not in my BitBucket commit history. It's like it never happened.

I was using SourceTree to merge a branch into master.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, in the situation you described, no new commit will be added to the master branch because the file contents were already identical to what was in the branch.

If you had merged with `--no-ff`, then Git would have created a new merge commit with two parents (your previous master and your side branch) that records the history of how the branch was merged.

Comment: This can't be right. `--no-ff` only changes the behaviour when a fast-forward merge is possible. In this case, the two commits are different so a fast-forward merge would not be possible in the first place.

Comment: Hvd, the two commits are exactly the same. One commit was on the master branch, the other was on a seperate branch that I merged back into master. Both commits contained ONLY the same code changes, no other code commits.

Comment: @Slayer0606 - unless they had the exact same commit SHA they weren't the same.  Introducing the same changes is a different matter.

Answer (score 0):

If you make two commits on separate branches, even if they contain the same changes, they are still separate commits.

If you now merge the two branches, you will get a merge commit just like with every merge. And if there’s no conflict, then the merge commit will not introduce any new changes.

But you will still have a merge commit that has two parents, marking the point in the history where the branches were merged.

Example:

```
       branch_a       after merge
          ↓              ↓
* -- * -- A ------ X --- M
                        /
* ------- B ------ Y --/
          ↑
       branch_b
```

Commits `X` and `Y` are committed to branches `branch_a` and `branch_b` respectively. Both commits contain the same changes. They are still different objects since—for example—`X` has parent `A`, and `Y` has parent `B` (there are more differences). If we now merge `branch_b` into `branch_a`, a merge commit `M` is created that has `X` and `Y` as its parents.